# How do I access a child components state in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

Hello I am working on a shopping cart project, where user can add/subtract quantity depending on the button clicked . The problem I am having is if I move state up to the parent component the **itemQty** is the same for all entities. So I moved it down to child component and that keeps the states separate for each product. This works up until I need to access that itemQty to calculate the subtotal.

- I have tried  passing a function from parent to child to return the itemQty but it ended up returning itemQty for each product.
- I have tried useRef, but I don't think it is ment for this situation and I ended up with some error.

Any help will be very appreciated.

**Parent Component**

```
export default function cart() {

  let total = useContext(getTotalContext)
  let setTotal = useContext(setTotalContext)
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([])
  const [sum, setSum] = useState(0)
  /*   const prices = products.map((x) => x.price).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) // use to calculate total price */
  const prices = products.map((x) => x.price).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)

  const itemQtyRef = useRef(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    // localStorage.clear();
    setProducts(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("products"))) // get add to cart data initially to create cart
    localStorage.getItem('count') === 0 ? setTotal(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("products")).length) : setTotal(localStorage.getItem('count')) // return length if no count total
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('count', total) // stores total for navbar after every change in dropdown etc
  }, [total])


  useEffect(() => {  // upload changes to products to storage every change
    localStorage.setItem("products", JSON.stringify(products))
    setSum(prices) // 
    console.log(products)
  }, [products])
  return (
    <div className="Page-Container">
      <div className="Product-Container">
        {products.map((product, i) => {

          return (
            <div key={i}>
              <Image
                className=""
                alt="Image Unavailable"
                src={product.image}
                width={300}
                height={300} />
              <h4 className="text-sm text-gray-700">{product.title}</h4>
              <h5 className="text-lg font-medium ">${product.price}</h5>
              <h6 className="no-underline hover:no-underline">{product.rate}/5 of {product.count} Reviews</h6> {/*Add stars to */}
              <button className="bg-black-500 hover:bg-gray-400 text-black font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded-full"
                onClick={() => { //remove product on click of x
                  setProducts(products.filter((x) => x.id !== product.id))//filters out by product id clicked
                  setTotal(total - 1)
                  //     setTotal(total-product.itemQty) // removed item qty from total
                }}>x</button>
              <QtyButton product={product} setTotal={setTotal} total={total} />
      
            </div>
          )
        })}
```

**Child Component**

```
export default function QtyButton(props) {
    const [itemQty, setItemQty] = useState(1)
    
    return (
        <div>
            <button className="bg-green-500 hover:bg-gray-400 font-bold py-2 px-4"
                onClick={() => {
                    setItemQty(itemQty + 1)

                }}>+</button>
            <button className="bg-red-500 hover:bg-gray-400 font-bold py-2 px-4" onClick={() => {
                if (itemQty > 0) {
                    setItemQty(itemQty - 1)
                }

            }}>-</button><div>Quantity: {itemQty}</div>
            
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: "if I move state up to the parent component the itemQty is the same for all entities" -- not if you use an array or object.

Comment: @ggorlen thank you for your comment. After posting this I just thought about that. I will give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

Lifting the state to the parent component is the right choice here.

But you seem to have gotten a bit of tunnel vision with the state. You should instead send in functions to modify parent state and have another state object which hold "purchase product data", indexed on product.id

```
// at the top
const [purchases, setPurchases] = useState({})

// in the state initializing useEffect
const _products = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("products"))
setProducts(_products)
setPurchases(_products.reduce((acc,p) => ({ ...acc, [p.id]: 
{quantity:0}}),{}))

// in returning render
    <QtyButton onPlus={() => setPurchases(purchases => {...purchases, purchases[product.id]: { quantity: purchases[product.id]++}})}
// onMinus={}
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all, it's not the good way.means calling a child function from parent .Normally what we do is passing the function to the child component from parent.means you can define the function in parent and pass it to child

but if you must need like this, please use [ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).
wrap up the child function(which u need to call from parent) with forwardRef and useImperativeHandle

for example

```
const QtyButton = forwardRef((props, ref) => {

const [itemQty, setItemQty] = useState(1)

   useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({

    handleqty(qty) {
      setItemQty(itemQty)
    }

  }));
   
  return (
    <div>
      <button className="bg-green-500 hover:bg-gray-400 font-bold py-2 px-4"
          onClick={() => {
                setItemQty(itemQty + 1)

            }}>+</button>
      <button className="bg-red-500 hover:bg-gray-400 font-bold py-2 px-4" onClick={() => {
            if (itemQty > 0) {
                setItemQty(itemQty - 1)
             }

        }}>-</button><div>Quantity: {itemQty}</div>
        
        </div>
       )
   });
```

in parent

```
 const qtyButtonRef = useRef();
 <QtyButton ref={qtyButtonRef} product={product} setTotal={setTotal} total={total} />
```

and call the child function by using

```
qtyButtonRef.current.handleqty();
```

Comment: I have tried your solution, but the handleqty() returns the setItemQty(itemQty) statement back when it console.log it in the parent. How do i get it to return the itemQty? I am not familiar with the imperativeHandler/forwardRef

Comment: two way we can handle. one is return the quality from the handleqty function itself

    handleqty(itemQty) {
      setItemQty(itemQty );
      return itemQty
    },

  other wise add one more function inside the useImperativeHandle for getting the state value and call that function from parent component after calling handleqty

ref :  https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-buck-lpv4nh?file=/src/App.js:150-267